# Duplicity install error: ImportError: No module named duplicity

Tags: python, duplicity

Can't explain the error message for duplicity:

```
ddd@T400:~$ duplicity -vi ~/Dropfold swift://bkp_dropbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 61, in <module>
    from duplicity import log
ImportError: No module named duplicity
```

It is just a vanilla install from apt. It was working fine on Ubuntu 14.04. Looks like the installation is failing (I have already tried to remove it and to reinstall it).

Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Anaconda installed you might need to force the system to use Python.

To do this:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question ... that was due to Anaconda. I need to force the system Python.

Comment: How do you achieve the switch conveniently?